# 15.04 builds fail to boot on USB

Tags: boot, usb, 15.04

I have tried more than a dozen times to build the Startup Disk on 4 different 2GB USB stick drives, with at least 2 different downloaded images, and all get the "Not a COM32R image" when boot is attempted.  Are the source images buggered?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1325801)
Here is a quick answer to boot into installer or live desktop,
When you see `boot:` prompt just press <kbd>tab</kbd> and you will see some options,
e.g.: install, live-install, memtest, hd ,..etc.
Type the option you want and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> then you are good to go.